# Equivalent OpenGL ES 2.0 Method to void glBindFragDataLocation(GLuint program, GLuint colorNumber, const char * name);

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

The online documentation at http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ does not give reference to the `glBindFragDataLocation(GLuint  program,  GLuint  colorNumber,  const char * name);` method. What is the equivalent to this in OpenGL es 2.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not equivalent, read below.

OpenGL ES 2.0 does not allow to emit more than one fragment output, you either write to `gl_FragColor` or `gl_FragData[0]`. This is one of the things that with plain OpenGLES 2.0 makes really slow deferred shading since you cannot define multiple targets.

If you are on **Tegra** you can slightly change your program to emit `gl_FragData[i]` using `NV_draw_buffers` extension, but you cannot use an user defined out variables, there is only `gl_FragData[i]` out variable that could output to different attachments.

That being said, and trying to answer your question, you need to change your fragment shader to use `gl_FragColor` or `gl_FragData[0]`, **there are not user defined out variables**.